# Missing policy in Group Policy Editor

Tags: group-policy

I am seeking to turn on IE Enterprise Mode: https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/turn-on-enterprise-mode-and-use-a-site-list

[image]

I followed the steps but there is no "Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list" policy listed. Am I missing something? I am on the DC.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have older versions of the Internet Explorer GPO templates installed on the machine you're opening the GP Management Console from. You can download the latest here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40905